# Should I dispose EventRecords from a EventLogReader?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Should dispose be called on the events that come back from the ReadEvent method of EventLogQuery?

```
        var eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery("application", PathType.LogName) ;
        using (var logReader = new EventLogReader(eventLogQuery))
        {
            var eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
            while (eventInstance != null)
            {
                eventInstance.Dispose();  //Should this be done?  Or is this not ours to dispose?
                eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
            }
        }
```

Should my code call a dispose on eventInstance?  Or is that something else's job?

Comment: If it implements IDispose, dispose it. You got the thing from a query, which is to say, you called a method that created the object for you. It's all yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it implements `IDispose`, dispose of it before it leaves the scope where it was created -- unless you plan to keep it around for a while for some particular reason. And calling `EventLogReader.ReadEvent()` is the kind of thing you should presume qualify as creation unless MSDN says otherwise (I checked -- it doesn't).

"Unless you plan to keep it around for a while" is why `logReader` should be deeply reluctant to dispose of the objects it created for you: It just can't know what you plan to do with them, so it should leave the decision up to you. It's not a bad idea to check MSDN if in doubt, but it would be strange if `EventLogReader.Dispose()` disposed of the query results as well. If you look at [`EventLogRecord` in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord(v=vs.110).aspx), it doesn't say anything about the subject, so just take `IDispose` as a suggestion to call `Dispose()` on the thing when *you* are done with it.